# conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: database, excel

I'm using conditional formatting such as:

```
=$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,3)
```

This will result in the 3 largest or highest amounts. But is there a formula that will result in automatically producing the top 10, or 9, or 8, or etc.? So I won't have to go back and change the format based on criteria for that given week?

In other words, I'm looking a formula to replace the "3" that will look at the range and produce the top 10, or 9, or 8, or etc.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What determines whether tyou want the top 3, 10, 9, 8, etc?

Comment: Can't you just use a cell reference in place of 3 and put your `n` in that cell? Note that your formula may format more than 3 values if you have duplicates

Comment: It depends on the count in my range. therefore...

Comment: so you want more cells formatted if there are more numbers in the range - what are the rules?

Comment: I'm actually looking for a format, if there such, that: in place of the "3" show the figures up to the 10 highest figures.  if there is only 9 numbers that will show those figures and so forth.  Something like =$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,(n<=(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))   But I don't know the proper code syntax

Comment: Currently if I have a 10 in place of the 3, and say 7 figures are in the range and the rest are 0's.  Every number in the entire  range is going to be highlighted because of I asked top 10 and 7 figures were appearing for that run.  I'm wondering is there a way to have only the numbers highlighted and the 0's not be...

Comment: I'm searching for a conditional format such as:  =$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,10) this will result in the 10 largest or highest amounts. I have to do this on a weekly basis. Sometimes depending on the week, there’s a Top 9 or a Top 8 or 7 or 6 and so on… Therefore, is there a formula that will result in automatically producing the Top 10 or 9, or 8, or etc. down to 1 (and excluding 0) so I won't have to go back every week and change the format based on the criteria on for that given week? Something like =$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,(n<=(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,(n<>0)))?  But I don't know the proper syntax…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Top/Bottom Rules, Top Ten Items... and select a value in the left hand window to suit (and change formatting if desired).

To exclude values of `0` from the highlighting, use Top 10 for 10 items but also Format only cells that contain, Cell Value, equal to, =0 and set no format. Make sure this rule is at the top of any others, applies to a suitable range and that Stop If True is checked:

[image: SO21292676 example]

Comment: I'm searching for a conditional format such as:=$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,10) this will result in the 10 largest or highest amounts. I do this on a weekly basis. Sometimes depending on the week, there’s a Top 9 or a Top 8 or 7 or 6 and so on… Therefore, is there a formula that will result in automatically producing the Top 10 or 9, or 8, or etc. down to 1 (and excluding 0) so I won't have to go back every week and change the format based on the criteria on for that given week? Something like =$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,(n<=(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,(n<>0)))? But I don't know the proper syntax…

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try a get back to you.  I was also thinking could I combine formulas. a Nested If inside a Conditional Format? An example...  =$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,(if(B2=10,B2,if(B2=9,B2,if(B2=8,B2,if(B2=7,B2,if(B2=6,B2,if(B2=5,B2,if(B2=4,B2,if(B2=4,B2,if(B2=3,B2,if(B2=2,B2,if(B2=1,B2,if(B2<>0,0))))))))))))))? Is that possible? I want a version of if the result is not 10 then it will try 9, & then 8 & so forth.  Until it reaches 0, * 0 is not highlighted...

Comment: For =$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,10), results in the Top 10 highest amounts.  Sometimes there is only a Top 9 or 8 etc… down to 1 (excluding 0). I need a formula that will result in the Top 10 or 9 etc. down to 1 (excluding 0), so I won't have to go back every week and change the format. Currently, the equation is highlighting the Top 10.  But if there were only 7 figures in the range, every number in the entire range is highlighted because the formula is resulting in the Top 10 (7 figures were appearing and the rest are 0's).  Is there a way to have only the numbers highlighted and not the 0's.

Comment: Coiuld you show me an example of "also Format only cells that contain, Cell Value, equal to, =0 and set no format."?

Comment: YOUHOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   I think I got it...   I put the 1st condition as "equal to" "0" w/ "No Format", and the 2nd condition as =$B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$40,10). Placing the "10" argument 2nd, in concert with the "0" 1st, causes the "10" argument essentially to be "up to 10". And if I have more than 10 it's not highlighted.    Thank you...   Thank you.. Thank you...   Can you see any flaws in my logic?

Comment: Another ? for you.  How can I work off of the results of 2 of those types of arguments & have only the results

Comment: Another ? for you. How can I work off of the results of 2 of those types of arguments(column C & G) & have the results highlighted in  (column A)...   A's arguments ie.  con1--cellvalue--equal to 0, No Format;  con2--formulais--=$G27>=LARGE($G$27:$G$150,10), Bold Format;  con3--formulais--$C27>=LARGE($C$27:$C$150,10), Colored Red.  Another quandry...

Comment: i hit the enter key by accident